Wrap when equal-width containers get too small to contain their content
I have a row flexbox with these requirements:

The flexbox has two child flex items
The flex items ALWAYS have the same width
As soon as the container becomes small enough that ANY of the flex items cannot fit their content, cause the flexbox to wrap.

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">LOOOOOOOOOOONG</div>
  <div class="item">SHORT</div>
</div>

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background: lightcyan;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item {
  background: salmon;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

As you can see screenshot, the flexbox never wraps.

And I want the text to remain in one line - so things like overflow-wrap: anywhere; are non-solutions.

Text on one line means that the items will never wrap since they will just overflow.

You have 3 requirements but unfortunately, only 1 & 2 are really possible together, #3 just won't (AFAIK) with the other requirements. Perhaps you need to rethink or explain the use case. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/qBzgbRQ

@Paulie_D No, this is what I want.

It’s not possible to easily do what you want to do. The only way would be to use Javascript to check the actual content length and adjust the layout accordingly.
If you can estimate the length of your content, you can get close using display: grid with grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(width_of_your_widest_child, 1fr)).
Read more


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background: lightcyan;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(12rem, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item {
  background: salmon;
  padding: 10px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">LOOOOOOOOOOONG</div>
  <div class="item">SHORT</div>
</div>



